# Parsing a second XML inside a parsing function using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to parse a "first.xml" and inside this parse function I have to parse a "second.xml" for every element in "first.xml". It looks as if jQuery would not parse "second.xml" until parsing of "first.xml" is completed.

My HTML File has a div where the Content is being appended:

```
<div id="Content"></div>
```

This whole code is embedded inside a $(document).ready(function({});

```
function parseXML(xmlFilePath, callback){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: xmlFilePath,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            callback(xml);
        }
    });
}

parseXML("first.xml", function(returnedXML){
    $(returnedXML).find("ElementA").each(function(counter) {

        name_of_Attribute_of_Element_A = $(this).attr("name");
        $("#Content").append(counter  + ". " + name_of_Attribute_of_Element_A);

        $("#Content").append("------ before parsing second.xml ------");

        parseXML("second.xml", function(returnedXML){
            $(returnedXML).find("ElementB").each(function() {
                name_of_Attribute_of_Element_B = $(this).attr("name");
                $("#Content").append(name_of_Attribute_of_Element_B);
            });
        });


    });

});
```

My Output looks something like this:

```
1. name_of_Attribute_of_Element_A
------ before parsing second.xml ------
2. name_of_Attribute_of_Element_A
----- before parsing second.xml ------
3. name_of_Attribute_of_Element_A
----- before parsing second.xml ------
name_of_Attribute_of_Element_B
name_of_Attribute_of_Element_B
name_of_Attribute_of_Element_B
```

instead of:

```
1. name_of_Attribute_of_Element_A
------ before parsing second.xml ------
name_of_Attribute_of_Element_B
2. name_of_Attribute_of_Element_A
----- before parsing second.xml ------
name_of_Attribute_of_Element_B
3. name_of_Attribute_of_Element_A
----- before parsing second.xml ------    
name_of_Attribute_of_Element_B
```

I also tried to concatenate my output and append it only once in the end. This means instead of

```
$("#Content").append(result);
```

I have used

```
myHTMLOutput = myHTMLOutput + result;
```

and in the end of my document I have used

```
$("#Content").append(myHTMLOutput);
```

once but it was the same result.

Is it maybe that jQquery doesn't allow multiple parsing of XML Files using Ajax? If so, is there an option to interrupt the parsing of the first file, finishing of the parsing of the second file and resuming with the parsing of the first file?

Strange detail: If I debug my code using JetBrains Webstorm the step by step output is correct. Only if I run it normally the output of "second.xml" is appended after "first.xml".

Thank you in advance for any help you provide.

Comment: I wanted to thank you all for your help. I have solved my problem. At first I tried to reconstruct your examples and hints. That means I tried to store all the contents of my XML files inside of arrays, then wait until I reveived a success from all ajax requests, then output the sorted contents of the arrays.

After a friend of mine looked over my code and asked me why I'm using Ajax instead of plain Javascript when I am only working on local files, so I don't need no asynchronous calls, it made me think. Now I have solved my problem with async:false. It was so easy in the end. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in `each()` and `find()`. You loop through all the "ElementA"'s (which is fast because xml no. 1 has already been completed) while the second ajax call takes time to complete.
So the elements of first xml are shown, and ajax for second.xml are fired, but take their time to do the ajax round-trip, hence you get them after.

A possible solution would be a different logic:

```
parseXML("first.xml", firstCallback);

var counter = 0;
var max;

function firstCallback(xml)
{
    var a = $(xml).find("ElementA");
    max = a.length;
    // do something with elements of first.xml
    readSecond();
}

function readSecond(xml)
{
    // do something with elements of second.xml
    if (counter==max) return;
    parseXML("second.xml",readSecond);
    counter++;
}
```

I have not tested this code, though, hope I got all right.

Comment: Thank you. This would explain the strange behaviour during debugging, where I stop the execution after every step and all the results appear in the correct order.

Comment: Yes but don't try my code, I'm very unsure if it works and it also depends on the exact logic of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem you are encountering is the 'A' in ajax ...."asynchronous". The first xml lopp is done before all the data is received from the secondary calls.

Here's a solution that uses jQuery deferreds stored in array. Content is stored in an object as it arrives. It is still possible for some of the  B items within each A item to be out of order but B's will always be with the correct A.

Concept nests `$.when( B ).done()` inside `$.when( A ).done()` at which point it parses the content object to the DOM.

**Uses $.post due to fiddle requirments**

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Dt75U/

```
/* store all ajax content in object*/
var content = {};

function parseContent(content) {
    $.each(content, function() {
        $('body').append('<br><br>' + this.a + '<br>' + this.b.join('<br>'));
    })
}
/* array to store nested ajax promises */
var deferreds_b = [];
/* A promise and ajax*/    
var xml_A = $.post("/echo/xml/", {
    xml: a
}, function(returnedXML) {

    var $el_A = $(returnedXML).find("ElementA");
    var total_A = $el_A.length;
    $el_A.each(function(counter) {
        var countA = counter;
        var name_of_Attribute_of_Element_A = $(this).attr("name");
        /* create EL A object , store EL A content, create array to push B content to */
        content[countA] = {
            a: countA + ". " + name_of_Attribute_of_Element_A,
            b: []
        }

        var xml_B = $.post("/echo/xml/", {
            xml: b
        }, function(returnedXML) {

            var $el_B = $(returnedXML).find("ElementB");
            var total_B = $el_B.length;
            $el_B.each(function(idx) {
                var name_of_Attribute_of_Element_B = $(this).attr("name");
                content[countA].b.push(countA + ". " + name_of_Attribute_of_Element_B);
            });
        });
    /* push B promise to array*/
        deferreds_b.push(xml_B);


    });
});

$.when(xml_A).done(function() {
    /* when A is done , wait for B to be done*/
    $.when.apply(null, deferreds_b).done(function() {
        parseContent(content);
        $("body").append("<p>All done!</p>");
    });

})
```